# Making an Action Listener for a JButton as a method?

Tags: java, swing, methods, actionlistener

How can I make this `ActionListener` into a method for a specific `JButton`?
(im aware its possible to throw it all in an method but yeah..hm.)

```
myJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       //do stuff
    }
 });
```

thx y'all,

edit: thanks everyone for the quick responses, my explanation wasn't very clear.

I looked into the use of lambdas and it was pretty much what I was thinking of, though the other ways are great to know aswell.

```
myButton.addActionListener(e -> myButtonMethod());

public void myButtonMethod() {
    // code
}
```

Thank you again, everyone.
I'll try to be more clear and quicker next time.

Comment: What do you mean by "make it into a method"? Please be specific and clear as possible. For instance, you've already got a method up there -- `actionPerformed(...)`

Comment: Create a method, add a regular action listener w/delegate, and call your method from it.

Comment: With a lamda or method reference, it becomes even less verbose: `myButton.addActionListener(e -> doSomething())`, or `myButton.addActionListener(this::doSomethingWithEvent)`

Comment: since im not working in `main`, i wouldnt be able to throw it in a class without a method, and im trying to figure out how I could make a method out of the code listed above, instead of just throwing it in a method -- if that is possible.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do. But also, this clarification is much too important to post in comments. Please edit your question, describe in further detail, showing in code what you're trying to do and how you're not succeeding. For example, why not do what @JBNizet suggests? Or why not do a method call from within your actionPerformed method above? Where are you stuck? What are you limited by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, your question remains unclear. Your code above **has** a method, one that code can be put into:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // you can call any code you want here
    }
});
```

Or you could call a method of the outer class from that method:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button1Method();
    }
});

// elsewhere
private void button1Method() {
    // TODO fill with code        
}
```

Or you could call a method of the inner anonymous class from that code

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button1Method();
    }

    private void button1Method() {
        // TODO fill with code
    }
});
```

Or you could use lambdas:

```
button2.addActionListener(e -> button2Method());

// elsewhere
private void button2Method() {
    // TODO fill with code
}
```

Or you could use a method reference:

```
button3.addActionListener(this::button3Method);

// elsewhere
private void button3Method(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO fill with code        
}
```

Up to you to try to be clear on what exactly it is you're trying to do and what's preventing you from doing it.